# How to generate a random DNA sequence in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, sequence

I am new to Matlab and I am trying to create random DNA sequence generator and so far I only found a way in generating A, C, G, T with equal probabilities, how do I assign different probabilities to each letter? All probabilities must add up to 1.

```
total_bp=10;
%open file
SeqLength=100;
bases = repmat('ACGT', 1, SeqLength/4);
for i=1:total_bp
%random DNA sequence
SeqLength=100;
Seq = bases(randperm(SeqLength));
display(num2str(Seq))
end
fclose('all');
```

Comment: This could be helpful: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html#mw_c510e755-389d-4e5a-8e0f-818dab2783bb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a cell-array of the bases

```
bases = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};
```

And an array of probabilities;

```
probs = [0.1,0.5,0.3,0.1];
```

Then you can draw a uniform random number and bin it:

```
bin = discretize(rand,[0,cumsum(probs)]);
```

and then translate to a letter:

```
seq = bases(bin);
```

In total:

```
n = 10;
bases = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};
probs = [0.1,0.5,0.3,0.1];
seq = bases(discretize(rand(1,n),[0,cumsum(probs)]));
disp(strjoin(seq)) %Join to single string.
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help, but I was wondering what would the equivalent of the discretize in Octave. I posted this question as a Matlab question since it is more popular than octave but I failed to realize that not all functions that are in Matlab are implemented in Octave. Thank you for your help regardless.

Comment: `histc` is somewhat similar, but the input might have to be slightly changed

Comment: @n1e2, If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it. That will keep the number of unanswered questions low, and it will support me.